# How to create a set-like array from something "deep" in json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
[
    {
        "item": "1",
        "values": [{"name": "A"}]
    },
    {
        "item": "2",
        "values": [{"name": "B"}]
    },
    {
        "item": "3",
        "values": [{"name": "A"}]
    }
]
```

and the desired result is: `["A", "B"]` grabbed from the name field

What's the "Javascript practice" of that? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? A basic for loop would iterate you through the object so you could obtain the values you want. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Heh, if you think that's deep... just you wait brah.

Comment: Your list has some invalid syntax in it - the "values" property is set to an array instance that contains a ":" separator in it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a syntax error in your nested array definition.

```
"values": ["name": "A"]  // this is not valid javascript
```

... I'm guessing you wanted something more like this?

```
x=[
    {
        "item": "1",
        "values": {"name": "A"}
    },
    {
        "item": "2",
        "values": {"name": "B"}
    },
    {
        "item": "3",
        "values": {"name": "A"}
    }
]
```

Second, to your real question - I would use either underscore JS or the Lodash library to help. In particular their map functions. So assuming you were using the object I defined above for x, and are using underscore JS...

```
.map(x, function(y){return y.values.name})
["A", "B", "A"]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: isn't "A" duplicated here?

Comment: Yes, because there are two value.name properties with "A". If you want to filter them and only get unique values there is another underscore.js function for that (coincidentally _.uniq())